# Проблема с просмотром строки с помощью for

Tags: c++

Мне нужно просмотреть строку. Найти в ней "!" или "*" и удалить эти символы из строки. Начал писать код -> написал. Он не компилируется... 3 ошибки.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");

    // получаю строки и длину первой
    char stroka1[20];
    char stroka2[20];

    cout << "Заполните символами первую строку: ";
    cin.getline(stroka1,20);
    cout << "Заполните символами вторую строку: ";
    cin.getline(stroka2,20);
    int len1 = strlen(stroka1);

    // вывожу содержимое этих строк
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Содержимое первой строки: " << stroka1 << endl;
    cout << "Содержимое второй строки: " << stroka2 << endl;

    // ищу знак "*" или "/" в первой строке и удаляю его.
    for (int i=0; i<len1; i++) {
        if ((stroka1[i] == "*") || (stroka1[i] == "/")) {
            stroka1[i] = "";
        }
    }


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что проблема в тех самых ошибках. Исправляйте их. Где, кстати, в вашем вопросе приведен полный текст этих ошибок? Что-то я их не вижу...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> stroka1[i] = "";
> ```

Так нельзя. Да и в сравнениях то же самое.

Присваивать можно только символ, а он пустым не бывает.

```
int i = 0;

for (int q=0; stroka1[q]; ++q) {
  if (stroka1[q] != '*' && stroka1[q] != '/') {
    stroka1[i++] = stroka1[q];
  }
}

stroka1[i] = 0;
```

Comment: У вас интересный код, но он не работает, почему-то.
Допустим, я хочу просмотреть весь ряд до конца, и заменить символы "*"  или "/" восклицательным знаком ("!"). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Что значит не работает? Ты просил удалить, я удалил. Для замены нужен другой код.

Comment: Я исправил ошибку.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Теперь всё работает идеально)

Answer (score 6):

Первая ошибка - **символ** в C/C++, в отличие от строки, указывается в одинарных кавычках. Так что

```
    if ((stroka1[i] == "*") || (stroka1[i] == "/")) {
```

должно выглядеть как

```
    if ((stroka1[i] == '*') || (stroka1[i] == '/')) {
```

А вот это я вообще понять не могу -

```
    stroka1[i] = "";
```

Вы всерьез думаете, что можно присвоить какой-то переменной (а `stroka1[i]` - это переменная типа `char`) пустое место и она исчезнет? :)

Вам нужно перекопировать все символы от текущего на один левее до конца строки (нулевого символа), включая его...

Comment: Ну в VB можно было...Правда, не совсем так, но суть та же.

Comment: Кстати, у питона у списков можно куски заменять, но синтаксис немного другой: https://ideone.com/4adrxS. И со строками не работает - кажется, они неизменяемые.

Answer (score 2):

Если задача удалить просто конкретные символы то вот пример

У std::string есть erase которому можно отдать итераторы от std::remove

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


int main() {
    std::string line{ "Hello! Hi*" };

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> stdout_it{ std::cout, "\n" };

    stdout_it = line;

    line.erase(remove(std::begin(line), std::end(line), '!'), std::end(line));
    line.erase(remove(std::begin(line), std::end(line), '*'), std::end(line));

    stdout_it = line;

    return 0; 
}
```