# Замена всех пустых мест в строке

Tags: c++

Я получаю от пользователя две строки, потом проверяю первую на некоторые символы -> удаляю эти символы. Тут проблем нет. Дальше мне нужно пустые места в конце заполнить восклицательным знаком "!". И тут проблема. Я написал проверку на пустое место в строке и замену знака, но это не работает. В чем может быть проблема?
P.S. размер массива 20, я знаю. Мне такой и нужен

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");

    // получаю строки и длину первой
    char stroka1[20];
    char stroka2[20];

    cout << "Заполните символами первую строку: ";
    cin.getline(stroka1,20);
    cout << "Заполните символами вторую строку: ";
    cin.getline(stroka2,20);
    int len1 = strlen(stroka1);

    // ищу знак "*" или "/" в первой строке и удаляю его.
    int i = 0;

    for (int q=0; stroka1[q]; ++q) {
        if (stroka1[q] != '*' && stroka1[q] != '/') {
            stroka1[i++] = stroka1[q];
            if (stroka1[q]== ' ') stroka1[q]='!'; // проверка на пустое место
        }
    }
    stroka1[i] = 0;

    // вывожу содержимое этих строк
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Содержимое первой строки: " << stroka1 << endl;
    cout << "Содержимое второй строки: " << stroka2 << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Послушайте, сформулируйте задание с нуля и абсолютно точно. Потому что мне, например, совершенно непонятно *Дальше мне нужно пустые места в конце заполнить восклицательным знаком "!"* - какие пустые места? Откуда они берутся?

Comment: Смотрите. Мне нужно получить от пользователя две строки. Дальше я первую строку просматриваю и удаляю из неё некоторые символы (*, /). Дальше я должен заполнить строку восклицательными знаками (восклицательные знаки должны отображаться после того текста).

Comment: В строке теперь i - 1 символов( последный вы инициализировали символом '\0'), но вы заняли память на 19 символов (плюс символ конца строки). Теперь вы хотите  инициализировать  все  19  -  (i - 1)  символов или как? Мне тоже не очень понятно.

Comment: 1. В С++ для работы со строками принято использовать std::string, у вас тут С-стайл. 2. Зачем Вам <stdio.h> ? a: в с++ вместо него есть <cstdio> b: что вы из него тут используете?

Comment: зачем на 2 строки, если можно все сделать с одной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сжатие строки с удалением определённых символов сделано, похоже, правильно. Но про пробелы ведь ничего не написано.

А вот **после** цикла сжатия достаточно пройти от текущего индекса `i` до конца строки , заполняя `!` **пространство, которое могло появиться после сжатия**.

```
char stroka1[20];
std::cin.getline(stroka1, 20);
std::cout << stroka1 << std::endl;
int i = 0;

for (int q = 0; stroka1[q]; ++q) 
    if (stroka1[q] != '*' && stroka1[q] != '/')
        stroka1[i++] = stroka1[q];

for (; stroka1[i]; ++i) 
    stroka1[i] = '!';

std::cout << stroka1;
```

вывод

```
123**dfg///asd/*dfg
123dfgasddfg!!!!!!!
```

Comment: Немного не то, что надо. Мне нужно не заменить весь текст восклицательными знаками, а после того текста, что есть, добавить восклицательных знаков до конца строки. 

Неправильно сформулировал задачу

Comment: Я так и понял задачу, но в коде, увы, на автомате инициализацию i поставил.

Comment: @MBo, так и меняй после того как дойдёшь до '\0'. Менять с '\0' до size-2, а size-1 установи в '\0'.

Comment: О, допиливание https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1060022/178988

Comment: @RaisaTinina, а почему пользователь другой?)